# sendDtmf on Xoom WiFI / Android 3.0

Tags: android, wifi, sip, tablet

Does the « sendDtmf » method from « SipAudioCall » class really work
on Android 3.0 / Motorola Xoom WiFi ?

I am developping a SIP activated application for Android 3.0 tablets
and testing it on Motorola Xoom WiFi (no 3G nor 4G)

I am able to :
- create a « SipManager » with « SipManager.newInstance() »
- use « manageurSip.makeAudioCall() » to retrieve my voicemail in my
SIP provider account
- in the « onCallEstablished » callback, I can use « startAudio() »
and « setSpeakerMode(true) », to hear messages

But when I try to use « sendDtmf(int) » to save or delete my messages,
nothing happens.

If I try to use an already developped SIP application "CSIPSimple", I
am also unable to send DTMF tones.

Should I wait for Android 3.1 to use this feature ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One more information : if I call :  
(TelephonyManager) 
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE).getPhoneType() 
in the "onCallEstablished" callback of the "SipAudioCall.Listener" 
included in the "makeAudioCall" (at this time I can perfectly listen 
to my audio messages), the answer is : 
0 : value of "TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE" 
I was expecting : 
3 : value of "TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP"    
The SIP API is maybe not fully integrated on Android 3.0 ?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4424e4a256dcb6a5/ca704ab9c2757c95?hl=fr&lnk=gst&q=xoom+wifi#ca704ab9c2757c95

Answer (score 0):

DTMF is not trivial is VoIP, so the problem may lie outside Android. I can help you troubleshoot that.

First figure out which DTMF transfer method is supported by your peer: RTP events, SIP INFO, or inband.

RTP events support is indicated in the SDP: a=fmtp:...

INFO must at least be in the Accpets header, if present, try it with a different client.

Inband DTMF requires tone-correct codec, usually plain G711.

Comment: Thank you ! When I use "Twinkle" softphone on my ubuntu workstation, I must choose "Inband" to be able to send dtmf. The other choices (RFC2833 or SIP INFO) don't work. Is this suitable for the android sip API ?

Comment: I don't know about Android, but for reliable inband DTMF transport (beep in the media stream) G711 (aka PCM) is the only widespread codec. You must select only that one. All other codecs achieve their low bit rates with aggressive optimizations for human speech, distorting the beeps too much for the far end to recognize.